# how to define linux system log root path var/logs in log4j.xml

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j

I have a  java application where the log files are written inside applicationfolder/var/log/application.log.

Instead of writing the log inside my application folder. It has to been written in linux root default log path var/log/application.log.

Could you suggest on this.

log4j.xml

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">/var/log</Property>
    </Properties> 
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5p] %d [%t] %c %X - %m%n
                </pattern>>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
       <RollingFile name="RollingFile-Appender"
                     fileName="${log-path}/application.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5p] %d [%t] %c %X - %m%n"/>
                <Policies>
                     <!-- <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/> -->
                     <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
                </Policies>
                     <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try a relative path for the log-path property:

./var/log

Answer (score 0):

Have tried with //var/log. It is working as expected